# Why does executing a comment in a Python breakpoint() cause '*** SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing'?

Tags: python, ipython, comments, breakpoints

After starting IPython, I execute these commands:

```
breakpoint()
# testing comment
```

It produces this output:

```
*** SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Thankfully this doesn't stop the code from running after I close the breakpoint() by entering 'continue'.

However in my case before figuring out breakpoint has this behavior, I thought this indicated a bug in my code, which slowed me from finding the real bug I was using breakpoint() to find.

I'm hoping there is a Pythonic way of thinking about this that makes it make sense and I'm too new to have learned it yet.

Also, does breakpoint() have any other behavior like this that could be non-intuitive to a new user?